# String to SrgsDocument

Tags: directory, speech

I have a string and I'm trying to convert it into a SrgsDocument so I can put it into my algorithm.

I   tried this but I knew that it would fail.

wordList.Items.Add(mystring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it I realised that if I write this code it will work:

```
            wordList.Add(New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsItem(mystring))
```